# IBM Worklight 6.0 - AutohideSplashScreen has no effect

Tags: ios, splash-screen, ibm-mobilefirst

I have ported my project to Worklight 6.0. I used AutohideSplashScreen so far, but this does not seem to have any effect in 6.0. Easy to reproduce:

1. Create a new project with iPad environment
2. Set AutoHideSplashScreen to false in config.xml
3. Deploy and run

   -> splash screen disappears automatically

This is important because my App now has an ugly flicker on startup.

Is there a workaround to get the proper splash screen handling again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known. Worklight at the moment disregards this option and the splash screen is set to disappear after the web resources have been loaded.

I cannot comment on future plans, but it is true that the current situation is not ideal and it is something we'd like to address.

To my knowledge there is no workaround.